# How can i deal with an error that shows 'lateinit property binding has not been initialized' while trying to display a list in a RecyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm new to Android development and I'm trying to display a list of todo on my RecyclerView but it is throwing an error that says `'lateinit property binding has not been initialized'` I think the error is from here :

```kotlin
 override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TodoViewHolder, position: Int) {

        holder.itemView.apply {
            binding.txtTitle.text = todos[position].title
            binding.cbTodo.isChecked = todos[position].isChecked
        }
```

Because that's the line of code in my Adapter the logcat is highlighting while I checked for error.  Please I need help in solving this error , my app crashes whenever I tried entering this Activity.

**my Adapter**

```kotlin
class TodoAdapter(var todos : List<Todo>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<TodoAdapter.TodoViewHolder>()
{
    inner class TodoViewHolder(itemView:View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)
    private lateinit var binding:ItemTodoBinding

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): TodoViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_todo,parent,false)
        return TodoViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TodoViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.itemView.apply {
            binding.txtTitle.text = todos[position].title
            binding.cbTodo.isChecked = todos[position].isChecked
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return  todos.size
    }
}
```

**My Class**

```kotlin
data class Todo (
    val title :String,
    var  isChecked : Boolean
        )
```

**My Activity.kt**

```kotlin
class NextAftertoolbar : AppCompatActivity() {
        binding = ActivityNextAftertoolbarBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        supportActionBar?.hide()

        var todolist = mutableListOf(
            Todo("Follow Android devs",false),
            Todo(" Learn ",false),
            Todo("Build",false),
            Todo("Land a role",false),
        )

        val adapter = TodoAdapter(todolist)
        binding.rvTodo.adapter = adapter
        binding.rvTodo.layoutManager=LinearLayoutManager(this)

        binding.btnTodo.setOnClickListener {
            val title  = binding.etTodo.text.toString()
            val todo = Todo(title,false)
            todolist.add(todo)
            adapter.notifyItemInserted(todolist.size-1)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As answered earlier, you should inflate and provide binding to your ViewHolder.

Here full working code.

```
class TodoAdapter(var todos: List<Todo>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<TodoAdapter.TodoViewHolder>() {

    inner class TodoViewHolder(val binding: ItemTodoBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(
        parent: ViewGroup,
        viewType: Int
    ): TodoViewHolder {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val binding = ItemTodoBinding.inflate(inflater, parent, false)
        return TodoViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(
        holder: TodoViewHolder,
        position: Int
    ) {
        holder.apply {
            binding.txtTitle.text = todos[position].title
            binding.cbTodo.isChecked = todos[position].isChecked
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return todos.size
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please add following code into your onCreateViewHolder method.

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): TodoViewHolder {

binding =
            ItemTodoBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context), parent, false)
        
return TodoViewHolder(binding)
}
```